# How do we use user access token to stay logged on to my FB canvas site even though another FB user is logged in through the original website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My scenario is somewhat like this: A user logs into my website with his FB credentials. I capture his ID and the FB access token (say, a long-lived access token). He exits my website, and returns back later. However, this time, his browser has FB open with a different ID. Would I be able to load facebook details of this old id (with which he had registered on my site) using the stored access tokens? Is it possible, or would it result in a clash between the old and the existing FB id?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but he/she should stay logged into your website, regaurdless if his authID changes.

Comment: yes his fb profile should be accessible on my website even if another fb profile is loaded through facebook.com on the same browser

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *why* would you want to do that? Since Facebook does not allow multiple user accounts for one and the same person, the only case where this would normally come into play is when another user is using my computer/browser – and why would I want you to read my info while that other person is using my device …?

Second of all, as long as the first user is still considered logged in to your site, it makes not much difference. But lets say some client-side method is called that updates the cookie information, then that’s where trouble might start. You might still be able to read the old user’s info, since you have his valid access token – but you’d have to use that token in your requests explicitly, and also address the account specifically, since the Graph API’s */me* would point to the new user.

But as I said, I can hardly imagine a real, practical use case here …

Comment: the use case is like this: say the site is abc.com and I register my fb id to abc.com, which stores the user access token so that whenever i log back to abc.com, i directly get access to my fb account. now say, i log on to abc.com from my friend's machine, who has his fb account opened on his browser. from the same browser i would want abc.com to open my fb account and not ask for authorization from his fb account.

Comment: Another site can’t „open” your Facebook account, they can at most _use_ it; but that requires you to login to Facebook first. If by login in to example.com on your friends machine you mean using that site’s _own_ login mechanism, then they might as well associate your FB uid & access token with your account with them and perform actions on Facebook with it, yes.